# Do I DELETE or NULLIFY the User's like/dislike if cancelled?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `table: dls` Where people `like/dislike` posts And it looks like this

```
[pid  -  uid  -  dl]
[1    -  4    -  0 ]
[1    -  5    -  1 ]
[2    -  9    -  0 ]
[1    -  1    -  1 ]
[1    -  8    -  0 ]
[2    -  4    -  0 ]
```

In matter of performance, Is it better to if i `NULLIFY[UPDATE: dl=null]` the `column: dl`

```
[pid  -  uid  -  dl  ]
[1    -  4    -  null]
```

When the User cancels his `dl` or just `DELETE` the row?

Comment: With all due respect, this is not a programming question, but a business logic one. Do you have a business reason for retaining the information that sy withrew a dislike vote?

Comment: @Shadow Nope, I just want it to be either `like` or `dislike`, Sometimes Users just cancels it, So i wonder if it is better to `UPDATE` the `dl` to `null` or `DELETE` the `row`.

Comment: Well, you answered your own question...

Comment: If a cancelled vote should be just like he never voted in the first place, delete it.

Comment: @Barmar Understood, Only if I need it, I keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the application.

If it is useful to have the information that someone removed a like/dislike, then keep the record and `NULL` it out.  Of course, this is only one method.  You could use a trigger and maintain a history table, if that is desirable.

If it is not useful, then remove it.

It is the application requirements that distinguish between the two.